# pip and Python in different paths

Tags: python, macos, terminal, pip

I've been having some trouble installing Python packages and then I noticed that pip and Python were in different spots, which could be the problem. How do I align them back up?

```
Macintosh:~ Ryan$ which python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
Macintosh:~ Ryan$ which pip
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/pip
```

And

```
Macintosh:~ Ryan$ python -V
Python 2.7.11
Macintosh:~ Ryan$ pip -V
pip 8.1.2 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages (python 3.5)
```

I'd like for everything to use 2.7 and hoping that fixing this will stop me from getting so many errors/notifications when I try to install certain packages like this:

```
Macintosh:~ Ryan$ pip install json
Collecting json
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement json (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for json
```

Comment: Well, first off, [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) is part of the stdlib, and so not pip-installable.

Comment: @MattDMo       Thanks -- New to Python, so maybe I just don't know the differences between some of them? Though is it important to get the paths matched back up?

Comment: I'm writing an answer for that. Is there a particular reason you want to use Python 2 for everything?

Comment: @MattDMo       Not really -- I'm just a beginner and I learned the basics through CodeAcademy and they teach it in Python 2 so I figured that'd be the best bet. Open to using whatever more advanced folks think I should be using -- just didn't want to have things break because of minor changes I don't fully understand.

Comment: Well, that's CodeAcademy's fault for teaching an old version, not yours. Python 2 is the past, Python 3 is the present and future of the language. You would be much better off learning with 3, then when you have a firm grasp of it going back and learning about where things differ if you'll have to work with Py2 code. You can pick up some bad habits starting out with 2 that are hard to break. The vast majority of 3rd-party modules these days support 3, so that's no longer the issue it was 5 or 8 years ago. Keep 2 around, just for the fun of it, but run your programs with `python3`.

Comment: What does `which -a pip` output?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham  `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/pip
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/pip
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/pip
/usr/local/bin/pip`

Comment: Just do  a `which -a python` also. You seem to have python2.6 in there too

Comment: @PadraicCunningham `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python`

Comment: Lastly, if you use  `/usr/bin/python` from a shell which version do you see?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham  `/usr/bin/env python
Python 2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec  5 2015, 12:54:16) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin`

Comment: Ok, not sure how you have 2.6 installed. Anyway  I would recommend using virtualenvs, most people coming to python end up with a lot of headaches from having multiple installs and things getting all mixed up,  a virtuaenv is also isolated from your system python which is pretty much essential for a working OS so screwing it up can be pretty costly  http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/. Also pyenv is another nice option https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv, its just a matter of activating whichever version you want to use

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set up `pip` for 2.7, just download [`get-pip.py`](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) and run

```
sudo /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python get-pip.py
```

and it will install `pip` and `pip2` for you in the same `bin` directory as the `python` executable. You should still be able to install packages for Python 3 using `pip3` or `pip-3.5`.

Comment: Thanks! Do I have to put get-pip.py in that folder first? Right now it's on my desktop. If I run that as is, I get no errors but it still looks like the paths don't match up. Also based on your answer above, I suppose I'm open to making Python match up by using 3 instead?

Comment: @Ryan You don't have to move `get-pip.py`, just use Terminal and navigate to your Desktop folder, then run the command above. If you want to use Python 3 as your primary Python version, you shouldn't have to do anything, just remember to write `python3 my_file.py` when running it in Terminal. `pip` is already set up for Python 3, as you indicated in your question. It's your choice whether or not to set it up for 2 now, or do it later as you explore the differences between 2 and 3.

Comment: Thanks again -- it says `UserWarning: Module pip was already imported from /tmp/tmpQS4RbJ/pip.zip/pip/__init__.py, but /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.0-py2.7.egg is being added to sys.path` and when I do `which pip` it still says `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/pip`

Comment: @Ryan did you use the full command I gave in my answer, or just `sudo python get-pip.py`?

Comment: I went to `cd desktop` (where my get-pip.py file lives) then ran `sudo /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python get-pip.py` (typed in my password) and sent back some of the message I get back.

Comment: Here's more: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 19154, in <module>
    main()
  File "get-pip.py", line 194, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "get-pip.py", line 172, in bootstrap
    sys.exit(pip.main(["install", "--upgrade"] + args))
  File "/tmp/tmpxqS5Dw/pip.zip/pip/__init__.py", line 213, in main
  File "/tmp/tmpxqS5Dw/pip.zip/pip/basecommand.py", line 179, in main`

Comment: And `File "/tmp/tmpxqS5Dw/pip.zip/pip/compat/dictconfig.py", line 565, in dictConfig
  File "/tmp/tmpxqS5Dw/pip.zip/pip/compat/dictconfig.py", line 332, in configure
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_handlerList'`

Comment: @Ryan: [You had it working for Python 2.7 earlier](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/30479638#30479638), what happened?

Comment: @I'L'I         No idea! Didn't run other commands that would change it -- just normal Python scripts. The only thing I can possibly think of is that I also use the PyCharm IDE that could've done something weird but I checked and the Project Interpreter is 2.7. I tried to install another package and `pip` was just gone -- then when I reinstalled it, it said it was already there? Now `which -a pip` gives `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/pip /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/pip /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/pip /usr/local/bin/pip`